# Resolving Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a simple script that gets text from a textarea element and then sends that text to an alert box. 
I am getting the error Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier when checking the code on chrome web tools and would appreciate any suggestions as to why this is occurring, thank you.

The error is occurring on this line `if input == "" {`

This is my code

```
    var submit = document.getElementById('submitbutton');
    submit.click(function(){
        var input = document.getElementById('inputbox').value;
        if input == "" {
            console.log('there was no input');
        } else {
            console.log(input);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a lot bad (not working) syntax. Second thing is you trying use jQuery library in DOM elements what won't work.
Here is corrected code.

```
var send = function () {
  var input == docment.getElementById('inputbox').value;
  if (input === '') {
    console.log('there was no input');
  } else {
    console.log(input);
  }
};
document.getElementById('submitbutton').addEventListener('click', send);
```

Try install JShint for your editor to avoid syntax error and keep learning. :-) If you want use things like submit.click(); you need to add jQuery to your project and use jQuery for 'grabbing elements'

Comment: Keep in mind jQuery _is_ written in Javascript, so you can do just as much with it as with plain vanilla JS. If you read the question, you will notice no mention of jQuery.

Comment: You need to swap the order of the `send` assignment and using it in `addEventListener`. You're setting the listener to an undefined value. Or use `function send` instead of `var send = function`.

Comment: Maybe you'll explain something to me: Why do people like to use `var f = function()` instead of `function f()`?

Comment: The difference is sneaky - the difference between var f = function () and function f() is how this code is hoisted. There is a lot articles about that ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Add parenthesis

```
if(input == "")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var submit = document.getElementById('submitbutton');
submit.click(function(){
var input = document.getElementById('inputbox').value;
if (input == "") {
    console.log('there was no input');
} else {
    console.log(input);
}
```

If/else statements require the condition to be in a pair of parenthesis (line 4)